# Magento customer group taxes

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to implement the check for VAT ids, and got stuck (the [VIES check](http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/vatRequest.html) being a new feature in **1.7**).  I configured the VAT checks to assign users to certain customer groups - and this works perfectly.

I have 3 customer groups: *Business In Romania*, *General* and *Business Outside Romania*. What I want is to add a 24% VAT tax for the first 2 groups, and remove this tax completely for "Business outside Romania".

I can add taxes per country in `Sales - Tax - Manage Tax Rates`, but that doesn't help me since I need to add the basically for all countries.

To sum up, here's the question: How can I add taxes per customer group ?
Also, can I do this from the admin panel alone, or do I have to create my own module ?

**Solution(s)**

1. Follow the steps Andrew suggested
2. Another options works great if you want the products to be shown including VAT, and remove it when a valid VAT is added. You create a promotion that applies to the "Valid VAT" customer group, that gives a percent reduction of `(1 - (1 / (YOUR_VAT / 100 + 1)))*100` (this will be an ugly number, but copy it with all the decimals). In this scenario, you may have a 0.01 error from time to time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A) You use Customer Tax Classes.

1) Create a Custom Tax Class

2) Assign the tax class to a customer group.

3) Create a new Zone and Rate. Assign the Tax percentage you need. Make it work for EACH country you intend it to work for.
You will have to duplicate the rules unfortunately.

4) Create a new Rule via 'Manage Tax rules', assigning your new Tax Rate(s), Customer Tax class etc. Notice there's a multiselect to select the new rules you made for multiple countries.

Customers in your group will now get this Tax applied to them regardless of where the location is.

By default you are going to end up with some replication of rates due to Magento not allowing you to select "all" coutnries at once.
This can be done via a custom extension (i've done this before) but not as standard.

B) Alternatively you can change your settings in the magento admin:

Set the Tax calculation based on **ORIGIN** rather than destination. This may or may not work depending on what you need for your particular setp.

```
System > Config > Sales > Taxes > Calculation
```

Comment: I initially got stuck at the "add a rule for each country". A quick php script to generate the import CSV and 10 minutes later it was working :) Thanks

Comment: yeah the database structure is simple so it's very easy to import them form CSV :)

Comment: I had a similar problem when adding in tax rules for EU countries, i started using a CSV to import, then I wrote a module which I may make public